# Can CUDA cores run things absolutely parallel or do they need context switching?

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, gpu, cpu-cores

Can a CUDA INT32 Core process two different integer instructions completelly parallel, without context switching? I know that it is not possible on a CPU, but on a NVIDIA GPU? I know that a SM can run warps, and if core has to wait for some information, then a it gets another thread from the dispatch unit.

Comment: It's the same concept as SMT ("hyperthreading") in a CPU, so it is definitely possible in a CPU, too.

Comment: [this course](https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/cuda-training-series/) section 3, gives an orderly treatment of this topic.

Comment: @Homer512 But hyperthreading isn't trully parallel, it uses virtual cores, am I wrong?

Comment: When you look at the architecture of a Zen2, for example, you see that two threads simply feed their instructions to the same micro-op queue. These instructions are then scheduled on the available execution units ("port"). A port is practically the same as a CUDA core. In fact, HT is more difficult than what CUDA does because in HT, both threads can have different privilege levels, states (32 or 64 bit) and virtual memory mappings. In CUDA all threads on a multiprocessor belong to the same kernel. They only differ in instruction pointer and register content

Comment: Oh, and "truly parallel": CUDA cores don't execute multiple instructions per clock cycle. They start one instruction per clock cycle and those can come from different threads. They are pipelined, so the result may be available after ca. 12 cycles, but they can start one per cycle. That's how having more threads than cores helps. Dependent instructions have to wait multiple cycles until their inputs are available. Other threads can step in because they are by definition independent. Same with HT

Comment: @Homer512 A port is different from a CUDA core due to the SIMD execution. 1 CUDA core is more a lane of a SIMD unit on a CPU than a port since all the thread of the warp must execute the same instruction. Otherwise it would be amazing since CUDA core (and so thread) would be pretty independent easing the implementation of many codes. Unfortunately, the number of port does not scale on CPUs comared to SIMD units (mainly because of schedulers and decoders).

Comment: @JérômeRichard right, disregarded that. The point about scheduling independent instruction still stands though, just on a larger groups.

Comment: @Homer512 Yes, indeed (it may be better to talk about SM, partition or scheduler in this context ;) ). Note that on new architecture like Turing the execution is a bit more complex than previous ones. AFAIK, the int32 and float32 units of the same partition can run completely in [parallel](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/nvidia-turing-architecture-in-depth/). It looks a bit like multiple ports per partitions while the decoding part appears to still be serial & in-order (though this information is not specified in Nvidia architecture white-papers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that it is not possible on a CPU, but on a NVIDIA GPU?

This assertion is **wrong on modern mainstream CPUs** (eg. since at least a decade for nearly all x86-64 processors, starting from Intel Skylake or AMD Zen 2). Indeed, modern x86-64 Intel/AMD processor can generally compute 2 (256 AVX) SIMD vectors in parallel since there is generally 2 SIMD units. Processors like Intel Skylake also have 4 ALU units capable of computing 4 basic arithmetic operations (eg. add, sub, and, xor) in parallel per cycle. Some instruction like division are far more expensive and do not run in parallel on such architecture though it is well pipelined. The instructions can come from the same thread on the same logical cores or possibly 2 threads (of possibly 2 different processes) scheduled on 2 logical cores without any context switches. Note that recent high-end ARM processors can also do this (even some mobile processors).

> Can a CUDA INT32 Core process two different integer instructions completelly parallel, without context switching?

NVIDIA GPUs execute groups of threads known as warps in [**SIMT**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_instruction,_multiple_threads) (Single Instruction, Multiple Thread) fashion. Thus, 1 instruction operate on 32 items in parallel (though, theoretically, an hardware can be free not to do that completely in parallel). A kernel execution basically contains many block and blocks are scheduled to SM. An SM can operate on many blocks concurrently so there is a massive amount of parallelism available.

Whether a specific GPU can execute two INT32 warp in parallel it is **dependent of the target architecture**, not CUDA itself. On modern Nvidia GPUs, each SM can be split in multiple partitions that can each execute instructions on blocks independently of the other partitions. For example, AFAIK, on a Pascal GP104, there is 20 SM and each SM has 4 partition capable of running SIMD instructions operating on 1 warp (32 items) at time. In practice, things can be a bit more complex on newer architectures. You can get more information [here](https://wolfadvancedtechnology.com/articles/nvidia-gpu-architecture).